# Discord Python Rewrite - help command error (custom)

Tags: discord, discord.py

So, I've made a help that works, but I want it to say something if the category that the user entered is invalid. I got a working code without the error if the category is invalid. The code:

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx, *, category = None):

    if category is not None:
        if category == 'mod' or 'moderation' or 'Mod' or 'Moderation':
            modhelpembed = discord.Embed(
                title="Moderation Help",
                timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
                colour=discord.Color.green()
                )

            modhelpembed.add_field(name='kick', value="Kicks a member from the server", inline=False)
            modhelpembed.add_field(name='ban', value='bans a member from the server', inline=False)
            modhelpembed.add_field(name='unban', value='unbans a member from the server', inline=False)
            modhelpembed.add_field(name="nuke", value="Nukes a channel :>", inline=False)
            modhelpembed.add_field(name='mute', value="Mute a member", inline=False)
            modhelpembed.add_field(name="purge", value='purges (deletes) a certain number of messages', inline=False)

            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}')
            await ctx.send(embed=modhelpembed)

        elif category == 'fun' or 'Fun':
            funembed = discord.Embed(
                title="Fun Help",
                timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
                colour=discord.Color.green()
                )
            
            funembed.add_field(name='meme', value='shows a meme from r/memes', inline=False)
            funembed.add_field(name='waifu', value='shows a waifu (pic or link) from r/waifu', inline=False)
            funembed.add_field(name='anime', value='shows a anime (image or link) from r/anime', inline=False)
            funembed.add_field(name='spotify', value='Tells you the targeted user listening on', inline=False)
            funembed.add_field(name="song", value="Tells you the whats the targeted user listening in Spotify", inline=False)
            funembed.add_field(name="album", value="Tells you whats the targeted user album", inline=False)
            funembed.add_field(name="timer", value="Sets a Timer for you.", inline=False)

            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}')
            await ctx.send(embed=funembed)

    else:
        nonembed = discord.Embed(
            title="Help list",
            timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
            colour=discord.Color.green(),
            description='Category:\nmod\nfun'
            )
        
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}')
        await ctx.send(embed=nonembed)
```

It works, but when i tried inputing a invalid category it sends Moderation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You erros comes from your second `if` statement. You just have to replace it with either:

- ```py
  if category == ('mod' or 'moderation' or 'Mod' or 'Moderation'):
  ```
- ```py
  if category in ['mod', 'moderation', 'Mod', 'Moderation']:
  ```

Here's why your statement is triggered when you input an invalid category:

- An empty string returns `False` (eg. `""`) and a string returns `True` (eg. `"TEST"`).
- If you don't put brackets, it will separate each `or` as a condition (`if category == 'mod'` / `if 'mod'` / `if 'moderation'` / `if 'Mod'` / `if 'Moderation'`).
- Since a non empty string returns True, when you input an invalid category, your second `if` statement gets triggered and it gives you the Moderation help message.

You can also use [`commands.Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20command#discord.ext.commands.Command) attributes to make some refactoring:

```py
@client.command(description='Say hi to the bot')
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Hi {ctx.author.mention}')

@client.command(description='Test command')
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('TEST')

@client.command()
async def help(ctx, *, category = None):
    categories = {
        'fun': ['hello',],
        'testing': ['test',],
    }
    if category is None:
       desc = '\n'.join(categories.keys())
       embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Help list",
            timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
            colour=discord.Color.green(),
            description=f'Categories:\n{desc}'
        )
    else:
        category = category.lower()
        if not category in categories.keys():
            await ctx.send('Category name is invalid!')
            return
        
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f"{category.capitalize()} Help",
            timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
            colour=discord.Color.green()
        )

        for cmd in categories[category]:
            cmd = client.get_command(cmd)
            embed.add_field(name=cmd.name, value=cmd.description)

        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention, embed=embed)
```

Comment: description=f"Categories:\n{'\n'.join(categories.keys())}"
                ^
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash

Comment: Sorry for the late response. (I was sleeping) But the code works! Thanks!